# After Chrome update in Feb 2020 for SameSite related issue, my IFrame still has issues even after following web config suggestions for .NET

Tags: c#, google-chrome, iframe, local-storage, samesite

So a client's client's issue is in an IFrame:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">    
<html>

<head>
<title>HTML Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<p>Below is an iframe.</p>
<iframe src="*LinkWithDirectAuthenticationHere*" width = "800" height = "800">
 <p>iframes are not supported by your browser.</p>
</iframe></body>
</html>
```

Once the user is authenticated, the user is redirected back to login page because the localstorage containing the logged user details is returning empty due to the website being in an IFrame (signing out automatically). This was okay before the Chrome Feb 2020 update.

The version of google chrome I am using is **80.0.3987.149** 
For some reason, even if my other colleagues has the same version, they are not experiencing this issue. Already uninstalled all my plugins and cleared cached and logged out of chrome, the issue persist in my browser (I am the only one currently able to replicate my client's client's issue)

After setting this in my browser, I didn't have the issue anymore:
[image: SameSite by Default Cookies Disabled]

However, this is not the proper solution.. So I try and did the following on my .NET app:

- Updated the framework from 4.5.2 to 4.7.2
- Bruteforce added in header (for now)
  [image: Code Owin SameSite None]
- Added this but no idea yet what the pre existing options should be: 
  [image: Code OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions SameSiteCookieManager]
- Added the following on web config:
  [image]
- Not sure why this attribute is not allowed:
  [image]

I have these as warnings when testing the application on my localhost:
[image]

Please note that disabling samesite by default cookies fixed the issue, but I have to take actions that the user does not have to change their settings and continue on like before.

**Additional Note:**

- I am not experiencing this issue on Internet Explorer, FireFox and Opera
- The link does not have issue when it is not on an IFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment Chrome enforces new policy only [for subset of users](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site) so your colleagues might see different results.

I assume you have checked the Chrome `Application => Storage => Cookies` view and confirmed your cookies come back with `SameSite=None` and `Secure` set up? 
[image]

If so, you might need to move your iframe over to `https` (looking at your screenshot it appears to be HTTP now) as `Secure` instructs Chrome to only send this cookie [over secure connection](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/faq#TOC-Q:-What-are-the-new-SameSite-changes-). To test whether this is your case, 
try disabling `chrome://flags/#cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure`

Comment: I figured out more of the problem I was having based on your reply... I was setting samesite=none; secure on my local, but my local of course doesn't have HTTPS, so the reason the application was failing.. so now I just put an if statement if the application is running with HTTPS add secure, if not just samesite=none; then I did that chrome flag and it worked :) Thank you very much!

Comment: @MilkTea027 I was of impression both attributes are required (that same website I linked has a mention somewhere). Just keep an eye on Chrome updates as it might break and you will be forced to do https